# Can't align label on a Segmented Control in an NSToolbar

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstoolbar

As you can see from the screenshot, the View button text is aligned properly under Allowed Toolbar Items, but once I add it to the toolbar, it's aligned to the right. Why?

[image]

Comment: That's a good question, because it works fine in a trivial sample app. You'll have to post some code or give some more detail.

Comment: (I meant to say it aligned to the right.) I have no code there yet, it's a new appl... just a default int main method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set sane minimum and maximum sizes for the toolbar item. I think you also have to make sure the autoresize masks (or constraints if you're using automatic layout) are set properly in the toolbar item's *view* (the NSSegmentedControl in this case). I don't have the "proper" settings handy but the min/max toolbar item size + correct autosizing behavior are the key here.

Comment: Yep, it worked. My min and max sizes were 70 and 100, it works once I make them the same! thanks.