# How to make NSToolbar label move with it's Icon when both of them are visible

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout, nstoolbaritem

My app has an `NSToolbar` with a horizontal `NSSplitView` below it. An `NSSegmentedControl` in the toolbar moves with the splitview's divider, just like the one in OS X's Finder. [NSLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutGuide_ClassReference/index.html) was used to align the two "views" from different storyboard "scenes". I shared this approach in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974865/align-toolbar-item-to-split-view-content-unsing-auto-layout-constraints/32564698#32564698).

However, I don't know how to move the label with the icon. I've set the `minSize` and `maxSize`, but the label is fixed. In the first screenshot below, the "View Mode" label is not right below the segmented control.

It will be easy to add constrains to the label if I can access it. But I haven't found the API in [NSToolbarItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbarItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSToolbarItem/view), which only has a public `view` property. I've examine the view's hierarchy (the second screenshot), but I don't think I should use the variables with the `_` prefix.

A related but different question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280710/cant-align-label-on-a-segmented-control-in-an-nstoolbar). That question doesn't take moving into account.

[image: the problem: label is not below the icons]

[image: view hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

You could try subclassing the NSToolbar setting the title to @"" and then creating your own UILabel and adding it as a subview? then you could reference it's property name and move it wherever you like

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think this is good since it will break the factory toolbar behaviours, i.e. show/hide labels and size changing.